# replacement for import.sql file in spring/hibernate project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my spring projects, I have hibernate configured to create the tables in the database based on my entity classes. Also, when I need insert some initial values on this tables, I put a file named import.sql on my classpath with the sql commands to insert data in the database. I wonder if there is a way to accomplish this import feature without need to place a import.sql file inside my project, using only java classes. Anyone knows if this is possible?

Comment: you have to store all sql statements in a array/list and execute statements on startup of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider two alternatives,

First one is not java only, but since you're using that stack, you can consider [Spring DBUnit](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/index.html)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/context.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@DbUnitConfiguration(dataSetLoader = ColumnSensingFlatXMLDataSetLoader.class)
public class TemplateIT {

    @Before
    public void after() throws Exception {
        IDatabaseConnection connection;
        IDatabaseTester databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester(JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_URL + "&sessionVariables=FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0", USER, JDBC_PASSWORD);
        connection = databaseTester.getConnection();
        QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(connection);
        DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(connection,
                partialDataSet);
    }


    @DatabaseSetup("../dbunit/data.xml")
    @ExpectedDatabase("../dbunit/expected.xml")
    @Test
    public void testDBUnit() throws Exception {
        ...
    }


}
```

The data are handled through XML, but as the library is focused around test it offers many utilities that outmatch dealing with SQL directly. Easier dealing with partial data, simplified assertion thanks to @ExpectedDatabase etc.

Secondly, one "java only" setup that I use often is to prepare data through hibernate entities. I'm assuming that you're using generic DAOs, even if not, its easy to set it up. Than in @Before methods of your test simply set up the DB to you're liking, a snippet

```
@Before
public void before() throws DAOException {
   Company company = new Company();
    companyDAO.makePersistent(company);
}
```

I favour this approach as in my view increases portability (often I use in memory DBs for testing), readability and maintaince. The downside is a lot of code in the tests, and a preparing data can get tedious for complex objects.